# REST API to store files on a (externally created) user directory on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: cloud-storage, rest, raspberry-pi, user-management

I am making a WebApp with nodejs/express backend and I need a solution to create a directory on my raspberry pi for each user on registration and allow the user to access the data by:
1. mapping it in windows explorer
2. through REST API
Other requirements:
- User group quota
- Getting the value of user quota and storage left
- Possibly headless
- Doesn't need port 80
- NextCloud or OwnCloud don't work for me

There is probably something fundamentally wrong with my approach, but - are there any solutions that would completely or partially do what described above?